# Bold math using mathspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, bold, mathspec

I can't seem to make my math come out in bold using the `mathspec` package. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\textbf{This line should all be bold: {\boldmath $17^2 = 289$}.}

\end{document}
```

When compiled, it gives:

[image: bm]

If `mathspec` is not used, then the math is bold, like it should be. How can I make my custom-font math bold as well?

Comment: Possibly related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603/math-in-trebuchet-ms.

Comment: Maybe some clever usage of \setboldmathrm command (from fontspec package) can solve this problem (but I failed).

Comment: At least it's possible to get bold math: `\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Times New Roman Bold}` Though all math would be bold then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Separating out the font setting for math and text seems to work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\textbf{This line should all be bold: {\boldmath $17^2 = 289$}.}

\textbf{This line should all be bold except the
math: {$17^2 = 289$}.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good idea!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t seem to work anymore (with a current TeX Live, see my file list at: https://gist.github.com/tweh/b34d45fda0165a880b201ea69047685b). Any ideas?