# Shifted hat above f in math mode with trebuchet font

Tags: symbols

How to write

$\hat{f}$

to obtain hat above italics f in better way?

[image]

```
\documentclass[article]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb}     
\usepackage{amsthm}        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pdfmapfile{+winfonts.map}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{trebuchet}
\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\hat{f}(\xi) 
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The problem doesn't happen with `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\hat{f}$
\end{document}`.  Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/73317) if you want others to be able to help you.

Comment: I added the MWE

Comment: Please read the link I gave. *That* is a minimal working example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}

\begin{document}

$\hat{f}$

\end{document}` (BTW, `\mathrel` doesn't make much sense for a function).

Comment: @frougon Excuse me. The cause is mine :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano Just for the `\mathrel`, not the rest...

Comment: What is wrong with MWE? `\mathrel` works but not with trebuchet font as in my example. I need this font.

Comment: A minimal working example is supposed to be **minimal**. :-) Non-minimal examples distract the attention, obscure the real problem and waste the time of every person trying to help you. You see, I have only done that so far: giving you instruction and link, reducing your example to the real issue and trying to convince you. No time to investigate the real issue itself, and I'll have to go (personal constraints, alas).

Comment: I edited it. My question is about the hat in equation mode in trebuchet font.

Comment: @Carly Now it is correct without \mathrel :-). You read with a lot attenction the comment of frougon.

Comment: `\renewcommand\rmdefault{trebuchet}` has no influence on the `$\hat{f}$`, AFAICT. It is `\sfdefault` that matters according to the documentation in `sfmath.sty`.

Comment: When I delete `\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}` it works but it is not trebuchet.

Comment: I don't have your `winfonts.map` file, but to the best of my knowledge, the `f` in your example is typeset in Computer Modern Sans Serif, aka `cmss`. You can use `\showoutput` to make sure. I get `\OT1/cmss/m/sl/10 f` with your example, which confirms my assertion. This is not a math font, and is used in horizontal mode inside an `\hbox`! No wonder math accents can't be placed correctly in these conditions.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what should I do.

Comment: I can't say “do this and you'll have what you want” (I don't know which math font you want...), but what is clear is that this setup uses a hack which prevents the math accent mechanism from working.

Comment: OK, thank you I will not use trebuchet.

Comment: I don't know trebuchet except by name, maybe it is fine. But I repeat: in your example, the `f` doesn't use trebuchet unless your `winfonts.map` overrides things in a way I can't guess (which is not clearly visible in your screenshot, anyway).

Comment: You can try `sansmathaccent`, like this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{sansmathaccent}

\begin{document}

$\hat{f}$

\end{document}` (found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7576/73317)).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think Trebuchet can be used as a real TeX math font (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/603/73317) for a very partial workaround, i.e.: 7 symbols taken from Trebuchet plus, I guess, many letters and digits).
2. Neiter the `\hat{f}` nor the `\xi` from your example are typeset using Trebuchet, as the `\showoutput` command reveals (`\OT1/cmss/m/sl/10` is `cmssi10`, Computer Modern Sans Serif “Italic”; `\OML/cmm/m/it/10` is `cmmi10`, Computer Modern Math Italic):

   ```latex
   .......\OT1/cmss/m/sl/10 f
   .....\OT1/cmss/m/n/10 (
   .....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^X
   .....\kern0.46007
   .....\OT1/cmss/m/n/10 )
   ```
3. That said, the [sansmathaccent](https://ctan.org/pkg/sansmathaccent) package appears to allow one to typeset maths in sans serif with correctly-placed accents when the `sfmath` package is used:

   ```latex
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{sfmath}
   \usepackage{sansmathaccent}

   \begin{document}

   $\hat{f}$

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Note this excerpt from the [`sansmathaccent` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/sansmathaccent/sansmathaccent.pdf):

> `sansmathaccent` is not a standalone package; it is a package to correct a specific problem that appears in `beamer` and `sfmath`. If neither of those packages is used, `sansmathaccent` will do nothing.
>   Observe also that `sansmathaccent` will only work with Computer Modern sans serif math text; if you use a package such as `helvet` or `pxfonts` to change the sans serif math font away from the default, `sansmathaccent` will not help you.